# PWM converters: operation over and under 50% duty cycle

Tags: dc-dc-converter, flyback, duty-cycle

I have a DC/DC Flyback converter based on the UC2844 regulator and I would like to use other regulators of the same UCx84x family.
Reading the datasheet, I found that there are regulators that can generate:

- **duty cycle** up to **50%**
- **duty cycle** up to **100%**

My questions are:

- Why shall certain converters operate at duty cycle <= 50% ?
- Could there be issues with a Flyback converter with duty cycle > 50% ?

**What I have already found out**:

- In this thread ([Why can't certain isolated DC/DC converters operate at over 50% duty cycle?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/414888/why-cant-certain-isolated-dc-dc-converters-operate-at-over-50-duty-cycle)) there is an explanation about Push-Pull, Half-Bridge and Full-Bridge converters, but nothing about the flyback;
- In this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fF-jFFOWSY4) there is an explanation about the Subharmonic oscillation issue, but in my case this should be solved by adding some slope compensation (as suggested in UCx84x datasheet).

Answer (score 2):

> *Why shall certain converters operate at duty cycle <= 50% ?*

Some converter topologies cannot run with more than 50% duty cycle because, if they did, both transistors would be activated together and there would be massive shoot-through of current. Typically, a push-pull converter falls into this category: -

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.mpsind.com/product-resources/push-pull-converter-applications-notes/).

> *Could there be issues with a Flyback converter with duty cycle > 50% ?*

Flyback converters can operate in the high 90% duty cycle region but, it can get problematic above 90% if you are not careful; it's easy for the output regulation to be very poor for instance.

Answer (score 2):

The case for flyback is an oft-repeated mistake, an oversimplification.

When analyzing the flyback topology, it is convenient to assume the transformer has a turns ratio equal to the desired DC voltage ratio.  Therefore the duty cycle will be around 50% at full load / CCM, the peak switch and diode voltages are twice the DC voltage on their side, etc.  We have this symmetry, and we can ignore other quirks that may arise from an odd duty cycle.  For example, input and output RMS currents are jointly minimal, switching area (V*I) is maximized, timing is least sensitive, etc.

So, *under this set of assumptions,* it is simply the case that CCM occurs at 50% duty cycle.

What is often repeated, is subharmonic oscillation occurs beyond 50%, *omitting the above set of assumptions*.

In reading anything, always be wary of what assumptions may have been forgotten.  Especially in something so oversimplified as an application note.  If they don't tell you how they arrived at that conclusion, how can you check it for validity?

So, it often gets repeated this way.  But what they *really* mean is, subharmonic oscillation occurs in CCM.  That's all.

Indeed, slope compensation extends the stable range.  When about half the sense signal is current and half is voltage [slope ramp], the stable range goes up about double, i.e. instead of 100% ripple fraction (CCM threshold), it's stable down to 50% ripple.

Likewise, slope compensation worsens current regulation / limiting, by the same amount: instead of peak current being limited, peak current is a function of duty cycle and therefore output voltage.  The output current goes up faster as V<sub>OUT</sub> drops.  This needs to be accounted for in the design, using adequate ratings of switch, diode, transformer, etc. to handle whatever operating conditions are expected.  (Maybe you don't bother, literally never expecting fault conditions to last any longer than the startup transient; that can be a valid design decision in some cases.  The point is to make a decision about it, and understand what consequences come from it.)

Typically, slope compensation is used to a maximum of 67% or so, as the spread in fault current is just too wide to reasonably deal with (~3:1), maybe even just during startup.  This only affords a 33% ripple fraction anyway, and if you need lower (say to use cheap powdered iron inductors), you really need a different control scheme (like average current control).

Whatever the case, in the process, you'll normally design for around 50% duty cycle as the nominal case, but the exact value depends on available transformer ratios, component ratings, etc.

A common application is, using a relatively low turns ratio for small offline converters, where V<sub>IN(DC)</sub> could range up to 400V or more, and the switch is only rated for say 700V (as many integrated regulators are e.g. [LNK623](https://www.power.com/sites/default/files/documents/linkswitch-cv-data-sheet.pdf)), so the switch peak voltage has to be lower than the 50% condition would give (over 800V!).  And the disadvantages of the odd duty cycle may not be important (for converters in the ≤20W range, efficiency is a lower priority, and the small components have relatively high ratings due to the higher surface area-to-volume ratio or whatever; these often operate well into DCM, besides).